# How to set custom layout and font in Exoplayer notification?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using `PlayerNotificationManager` for displaying playback notifications in my application. Everything is working fine but I want to add my application's logo in the notification with custom fonts.

I changed the play & pause buttons on the notification by adding `drawables.xml`. But can't find a way to change the font.

So, how can I change the default notification layout and characteristics that Exoplayer provides?

**Edit:**
I have seen [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7576) issue on Github which says that we need to extend `PlayerNotificationManager` in order to use custom layout. But I can't seem to get it working.

Here is my code:

```
 private void setPlayerNotificationManager(Player player) {


    playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager(context, "123", 1234, mediaDescriptionAdapter);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseNavigationActions(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setUsePlayPauseActions(true);
    playerNotificationManager.setRewindIncrementMs(0);
    playerNotificationManager.setFastForwardIncrementMs(0);
    //playerNotificationManager.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    playerNotificationManager.setColorized(true);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseChronometer(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);

}
```

Comment: I've look around in the exoplayer documentation and source but I haven't found anything you could use directly, you should probably ask directly on the repo

Comment: Yesterday, I have seen an issue on the repo where it is told that, we have to extend `playerNotificationManager` class to use custom layout. But I couldn’t get it working. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Biscuit Here is the link to the issue on Github: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said on the repo you need to extends the `PlayerNotificationManager` to do that you need to create this [class](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.java) and copy everything inside your project, and then add the layout you want to use as described in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification#java)

You need to add your layout in the `builder` [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/8a0d52be4b5402af0987fc7d009bc49977c72b67/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.java#L1080)

Comment: I copied the whole class & made the changes. It's not working. The default notification layout prevails. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you changed the import in the file that contains your function `setPlayerNotificationManager ` ? You need to import `PlayerNotificationManager` from your project and not the one from `Exoplayer`

Comment: Yes, I have changed that. Also registered the Broadcast receiver in my Manifest. It is declared in here: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.java#L1365

Comment: Now, my custom layout loads but without any buttons. I don't know how to add that in the layout ( I mean the button id's)

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're missing but take a look at that https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Actions to add button to your layout, basically you need to re-do what `Exoplayer` was doing for you in the background